# vb.net multicolumn combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, multiple-columns

would someone please tells me how to populate a combobox with two or more columns? I have been trying to accomplish this for quite some time but with no results. I would appreciate any help. thank you

Comment: I think you need to use third party tool.

Comment: what is a third party tool? how can i use them in my project?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked in to this myself and unfortunately there is no such thing as combo box with multicolumns. I got round it by creating my own control, but it was a lot of work for what it is, i would suggest finding a third party tool that does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dev Express controls, there is control called Lookupedit it will show multiple columns

Comment: How can i use them? I copied one code in a new form but all error! Please help

Comment: have u added the references of DevExpress?

Comment: Not actually. Would you please guide me to do that?

Comment: First you need to Install Dev Express on your system...... and then add a particular dll reference to your project.

Go to Solution Explorer and add a reference by right clicking on References

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's struggling with this still, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72697722/19152103).

for short answer you can use **SyncFusion MultiColumnComboBox** (documentation [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/multicolumn-combobox/overview) for c# or [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/multicolumn-combobox/getting-started) for VB). If you follow the first link, it will direct you to my answer on a similar question with an example on code.