# Multicolumn combobox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm new to vb.net, arriving from MsAccess.
I cant seem to find a way to create a combobox multicolumn with header like in the MsAccess combobox. At this point i start to believe that is impossible. Is there anyone here in the Stackoverflow community who has reached the solution for this problem?

Comment: It is possible and there are examples on the web. As it stands, your question is to broad for SO. You need to do the research, find an appropriate example and make an attempt to implement it. If what you try doesn't work, you need to show us what you did and tell us what happened when you did it. You need to be specific about the issue.

Comment: You also didn't specify the GUI Platform of your app (e.g., WPF, WinForms etc.)

Comment: Sorry John but i'm still new with this forum. I'lltry to be more specific next time.
For Jimi, i suse WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SyncFusion multi-column combobox for it, [Documentation here](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/multicolumn-combobox/overview), it includes small examples and is simple to use.

Code for C# ([check documentation for VB](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/multicolumn-combobox/getting-started))

```
 query = "SELECT ID, Descricao FROM tab_tasks";

 adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
 adapter.Fill(ds, "idtask");

 DataTable dataTable1 = ds.Tables["idtask"];

 sfComboBox2.DataSource = dataTable1;
 sfComboBox2.DisplayMember = "ID";
```

This being the base of it, set your data as a datatable and use it as DataSource to your ComboBox.

`DisplayMember` is the member displayed when you choose one of the values.

Comment: Thanks AcisSys and marc_s but i noticed that SyncFusion is not free, only for 30 days trial.....

Comment: if this answer doesnt work, try doing like John said in a comment to your question and search other ways, try them and post the error it gives.